Athena Query exhausted resources at this scale factor error
I have below SQL query that runs as to aggregate data, with intermediary steps. However I run into "Query exhausted resources at this scale factor error" however I change it.
I read the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/performance-tuning.html and tried following the ideas conveyed regarding joins avoiding ordering, only getting required columns etc, but still unable to resolve the issue.
How else can I optimize the query, or otherwise make it work within the given resourses?
WITH turnit_product_activity_views AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            entire_table.basketcode,
            entire_table.productcode,
            entire_table.transactionstatus,
            entire_table.transactioncode,
            entire_table.isinboundjourneyway,
            entire_table.type,
            entire_table.code,
            entire_table.operationdatetime,
            entire_table.seatclass,
            entire_table.journeyoriginstopcode,
            entire_table.destinationstopcode,
            entire_table.departuredatetime,
            entire_table.nblegoutbound,
            entire_table.nbleginbound,
            entire_table.arrivaldatetime,
            entire_table.travelaccountid,
            entire_table.journeydestinationstopcode,
            entire_table.originstopcode,
            entire_table.legorder
        FROM "prod-se_delta_glue_database"."turnit_product_activity_view" AS entire_table
        WHERE entire_table.type = 'TRANSACTION_TYPE.BUS_TICKET'
        AND entire_table.basketcode IN (
            SELECT current_table.basketcode
            FROM "prod-se_delta_glue_database"."turnit_product_activity_view" AS current_table
            WHERE current_table."$path" = 's3://prod-se-delta-lake-bucket/turnit_product_activity_view/part-00000-6ae7752a-1ed4-4505-bce6-11c0d27f853b-c000.snappy.parquet'
        )
    ),
    selected_product_codes AS (
        SELECT
            MIN(productcode) as used_product_code,
            basketcode
        FROM turnit_product_activity_views as main_table
        GROUP BY basketcode
    ),
    nr_tickets AS (
        SELECT
            t.productcode as used_product_code,
            t.basketcode,
            COUNT(DISTINCT t.productcode) as Nr_Tickets__c
        FROM turnit_product_activity_views t
        JOIN selected_product_codes spc ON spc.used_product_code = t.productcode
        GROUP BY t.productcode, t.basketcode
    ),
    bus_tickets AS (
        SELECT 
            nr_tickets.used_product_code AS Product_Code__c,
            nr_tickets.basketcode AS Basket_Code__c,
            main_table.transactionstatus AS Transcation_Status__c,
            main_table.transactioncode AS Transcation_Code__c,
            main_table.isinboundjourneyway AS Is_Inbound_Journey__c,
            main_table.type as Type__c,
            main_table.code as Channel__c,
            main_table.operationdatetime as Operation_Date_Time__c,
            main_table.seatclass as Seat_Class__c,
            main_table.journeyoriginstopcode as Journey_Origin_Stop_Code__c,
            main_table.destinationstopcode as Destination_Stop_Code__c,
            main_table.departuredatetime as Departure_Date_Time__c,
            main_table.nblegoutbound as Number_of_leg_for_Outbound__c,
            main_table.nbleginbound as Number_of_leg_for_Inbound__c,
            main_table.arrivaldatetime as Arrival_Date_Time__c,
            main_table.travelaccountid as Traveler_Account_Id__c,
            main_table.journeydestinationstopcode as Journey_Destination_Stop_Code__c,
            main_table.originstopcode as Origin_Stop_Code__c,
            main_table.legorder as Leg_Order__c,
            nr_tickets.Nr_Tickets__c AS Nr_Tickets__c
        FROM turnit_product_activity_views as main_table
        JOIN nr_tickets ON main_table.productcode = nr_tickets.used_product_code
        and main_table.basketcode = nr_tickets.basketcode
    ),
    temp_status_groups AS (
        SELECT
            Product_Code__c,
            Transcation_Code__c,
            COUNT(DISTINCT Transcation_Status__c) AS status_count,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Transcation_Status__c = 'TRANSACTION_STATUS.SOLD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sold_count,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Transcation_Status__c = 'TRANSACTION_STATUS.RETURNED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS returned_count
        FROM bus_tickets
        GROUP BY Product_Code__c, Transcation_Code__c
    ),
    bus_tickets_with_cancel_status AS (
        SELECT bt.*, 
            CASE 
                WHEN tsg.status_count = 2 AND tsg.sold_count > 0 AND tsg.returned_count > 0 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
            END AS Cancelled__c
        FROM bus_tickets bt
        LEFT JOIN temp_status_groups tsg 
        ON bt.Product_Code__c = tsg.Product_Code__c
        AND bt.Transcation_Code__c = tsg.Transcation_Code__c
    ),
    status_info AS (
        SELECT 
            Product_Code__c,
            COUNT(*) AS total_tickets,
            SUM(CAST(Cancelled__c AS INTEGER)) AS cancelled_tickets
        FROM bus_tickets_with_cancel_status
        GROUP BY Product_Code__c
    ),
    sold_max_op_time AS (
        SELECT 
            Product_Code__c,
            MAX(Operation_Date_Time__c) AS max_op_time
        FROM bus_tickets_with_cancel_status
        WHERE Transcation_Status__c = 'TRANSACTION_STATUS.SOLD'
        GROUP BY Product_Code__c
    ),
    journey_tickets AS (
        SELECT 
            bt.*
        FROM bus_tickets_with_cancel_status bt
        JOIN status_info si ON bt.Product_Code__c = si.Product_Code__c
        LEFT JOIN sold_max_op_time sm ON bt.Product_Code__c = sm.Product_Code__c
    WHERE 
        (si.cancelled_tickets = si.total_tickets 
            AND bt.Transcation_Status__c = 'TRANSACTION_STATUS.SOLD' 
            AND bt.Operation_Date_Time__c = sm.max_op_time)
        OR
        (si.cancelled_tickets < si.total_tickets 
            AND bt.Cancelled__c = 0)
    ),
    journey_type AS (
        SELECT
            Product_Code__c,
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 'One Way'
                WHEN COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN Channel__c IN ('JOURNEY_WAY.ONE_WAY', 'AS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 'One Way'
                ELSE 'Two Way'
            END AS Journey_Type__c
        FROM journey_tickets
        GROUP BY Product_Code__c
    ),
    journey_tickets_w_type AS (
        SELECT
            jt.*,
            jtype.Journey_Type__c AS Journey_Type__c
        FROM journey_tickets jt
        JOIN journey_type jtype ON jt.Product_Code__c = jtype.Product_Code__c
    ),
    temp_journey_one_way AS (
        SELECT
            Product_Code__c AS Journey_Id__c,
            Journey_Type__c,
            MIN(Operation_Date_Time__c) AS Booking_Date__c,
            MIN(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'One Way' THEN Departure_Date_Time__c ELSE NULL END) AS Departure_Date__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'One Way' THEN Arrival_Date_Time__c ELSE NULL END) AS Arrival_Date__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'One Way' THEN Journey_Origin_Stop_Code__c ELSE NULL END) AS Ticket_Origin__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'One Way' THEN Destination_Stop_Code__c ELSE NULL END) AS Ticket_Destination__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'One Way' THEN Number_of_leg_for_Outbound__c ELSE NULL END) AS Nr_Legs__c,
            CASE WHEN SUM(Cancelled__c) = 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS Cancelled__c,
            MAX(Traveler_Account_Id__c) AS Account_Master_Detail__r,
            MAX(Nr_Tickets__c) AS Nr_Tickets__c,
            NULL AS Departure_Date_Outbound__c,
            NULL AS Departure_Date_Inbound__c,
            NULL AS Arrival_Date_Outbound__c,
            NULL AS Arrival_Date_Inbound__c,
            NULL AS Nr_Legs_Outbound__c,
            NULL AS Nr_Legs_Inbound__c,
            '0123Y000000dbzhQAA' AS RecordTypeId
        FROM journey_tickets_w_type
        WHERE Journey_Type__c = 'One Way'
        GROUP BY Product_Code__c, Journey_Type__c, Cancelled__c
    ),
    temp_journey_two_way AS (
        SELECT
            Product_Code__c AS Journey_Id__c,
            Journey_Type__c,
            MIN(Operation_Date_Time__c) AS Booking_Date__c,
            MIN(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'Two Way' AND Is_Inbound_Journey__c = FALSE THEN Departure_Date_Time__c ELSE NULL END) AS Departure_Date_Outbound__c,
            MIN(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'Two Way' AND Is_Inbound_Journey__c = TRUE THEN Departure_Date_Time__c ELSE NULL END) AS Departure_Date_Inbound__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'Two Way' AND Is_Inbound_Journey__c = FALSE THEN Arrival_Date_Time__c ELSE NULL END) AS Arrival_Date_Outbound__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'Two Way' AND Is_Inbound_Journey__c = TRUE THEN Arrival_Date_Time__c ELSE NULL END) AS Arrival_Date_Inbound__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'Two Way' AND Is_Inbound_Journey__c = FALSE THEN Journey_Origin_Stop_Code__c ELSE NULL END) AS Ticket_Origin__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'Two Way' AND Is_Inbound_Journey__c = FALSE THEN Journey_Destination_Stop_Code__c ELSE NULL END) AS Ticket_Destination__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'Two Way' THEN Number_of_leg_for_Outbound__c ELSE NULL END) AS Nr_Legs_Outbound__c,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Journey_Type__c = 'Two Way' THEN Number_of_leg_for_Inbound__c ELSE NULL END) AS Nr_Legs_Inbound__c,
            CASE WHEN SUM(Cancelled__c) = 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS Cancelled__c,
            MAX(Traveler_Account_Id__c) AS Account_Master_Detail__r,
            MAX(Nr_Tickets__c) AS Nr_Tickets__c,
            NULL AS Departure_Date__c,
            NULL AS Arrival_Date__c,
            NULL AS Nr_Legs__c,
            '0123Y000000dbzrQAA' AS RecordTypeId
        FROM journey_tickets_w_type
        WHERE Journey_Type__c = 'Two Way'
        GROUP BY Product_Code__c, Journey_Type__c, Cancelled__c
    ),
    journey AS (
        SELECT 
            Journey_Id__c, 
            Journey_Type__c, 
            Booking_Date__c, 
            Departure_Date_Outbound__c, 
            Departure_Date_Inbound__c, 
            Arrival_Date_Outbound__c, 
            Arrival_Date_Inbound__c, 
            Ticket_Origin__c, 
            Ticket_Destination__c, 
            Nr_Legs_Outbound__c, 
            Nr_Legs_Inbound__c, 
            Cancelled__c, 
            Account_Master_Detail__r, 
            Nr_Tickets__c, 
            Departure_Date__c, 
            Arrival_Date__c, 
            Nr_Legs__c,
            RecordTypeId
        FROM temp_journey_one_way
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            Journey_Id__c, 
            Journey_Type__c, 
            Booking_Date__c, 
            Departure_Date_Outbound__c, 
            Departure_Date_Inbound__c, 
            Arrival_Date_Outbound__c, 
            Arrival_Date_Inbound__c, 
            Ticket_Origin__c, 
            Ticket_Destination__c, 
            Nr_Legs_Outbound__c, 
            Nr_Legs_Inbound__c, 
            Cancelled__c, 
            Account_Master_Detail__r, 
            Nr_Tickets__c, 
            Departure_Date__c, 
            Arrival_Date__c, 
            Nr_Legs__c,
            RecordTypeId
        FROM temp_journey_two_way
    )
    SELECT * FROM journey


Your query is rather complex. It would appear that the complexity, combined with your volume of data, is too complex for Amazon Athena to process. An alternative approach would be to create separate tables for each of the with queries, and then a final statement that references those tables instead of the using with. This is how tools like dbt encourage data processing.

@JohnRotenstein thank you for taking your time to provide the input, I will look at what dbt encourages and see if it possible to have the tsböes pre-created.

After some trial, i think athena is using some validation (maybe with AI?). So if your query is too complex without using LIMIT, athena directly throw an "Query exhausted resources at this scale factor error" error.
So just for workaround, can you try to give LIMIT in the end of your query. (Its working with my complex query, idk if its working with yours)
